# How to access parent view of activity in fragment through dataBinding

Tags: android, data-binding, fragment

I am using data binding and i want to access activity view in my fragment using data binding because i want to display some message on the main container of activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can update it using Interfaces
For the first create an interface in your fragment ILayoutUpdater with a method update() and send your params to it.

```
public interface ILayoutUpdater{
 void update(String update);
}
```

Implement the interface in your fragment's activity you'll need to override your the update method in activity

```
@Override
public void update(String update){
binding.myText.setText(update);
}
```

Now back in your fragment create a class variable of this interface and initialize it in `onAttach(Context ctx)` and then use `layoutUpdater.update("data")` where ever you want from your fragment.

```
private ILayoutUpdater layoutUpdater;

@override
public void onAttach(Context context){
layoutUpdater = context;
}
```